# Ангел(-)хранитель: как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Встречаю кучу вариантов написания: и через дефис, и в два слова, и с большой буквы, и с маленькой. А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ангел-хранитель](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/), ангела-хранителя.

Comment: В литературе религиозного характера слово "ангел" пишется с большой буквы. Например, Ангел-хранитель, Ангел Божий.

Comment: @Надюшка, я как "воинствующий" атеист, считаю это орфографической ошибкой. :) Ангел-хранитель может являться именем собственным и писаться с заглавной буквы, только в случае обращения к конкретному лицу именуемому ангелом-хранителем. То есть это возможно, например, в молитве, где обращаются именно к своему ангелу-хранителю, но во всех остальных ситуациях, подобное написание будет ошибкой.

Comment: О! А я подумала, что, если бы спросили мое мнение, то писала бы "ангел", когда имеется в виду сравнение или эпитет (переносное значение), и "Ангел", когда значение прямое. :)